Return a list of names if a column in the same row is empty
I have the following values in Sheet A:
   A         B
1 Josh     Awarded XP
2 Jane     (blank)
3 Peter    (blank)
4 Mary     (blank)
5 Josh     (blank)
6 Peter    (blank)

I want to reflect the above names (in column A) in Sheet B without duplicates if column B is blank.
So in Sheet B it'll look like this
              A
1 Names that yet to receive XP:
2 Jane
3 Peter
4 Mary
5 Josh

I'll be continuously adding names to column A in Sheet A, so I'd would like Sheet B to update continuously as well with the newly added values from Sheet A.

Just to confirm, even though Josh has an entry with "Awarded XP" you still want to include the blank value?

You can use the FILTER function, filtering on blanks in the B column:
=FILTER(sheet1!A2:A6,ISBLANK(sheet1!B2:B6))
and to avoid having to change the range when you add more rows, convert the data to a Table first. Then the formula becomes:
=FILTER(Table1[A],ISBLANK(Table1[B]))
To get rid of duplicates change this to:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[A],ISBLANK(Table1[B])))

Thanks! I think you mean ISBLANK(sheet1!B2:B6) right? Currently I'm using =FILTER(sheet1!A:A,ISBLANK(sheet1!B:B)) but it doesn't seem to be removing the duplicates

You are right, I'll edit my answer.

Omg, you're awesome - thank you!! :)

In Google Sheets your infinite range formula could be
=UNIQUE(QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"Select A Where B=''"))

Or
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!B:B=""))

